# How to conditionally set a style class when last item of ui:repeat is reached?

Tags: css, jsf-2

I want to have a class on a div, if it is the last one in my repeat.

I have now:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myCollection}" var="item"  varStatus="status">
<div class="last">#{item.text}</div>
</ui:repeat>
```

but I want the class last just on the last div...

```
#{status.last}
```

is true, if it is the last div. But how can I get the class to the div?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Solution 1 if you may afford not to be compatible with IE8 :**

Don't do this in JSF, this breaks the purpose of having a CSS to isolate the style from the data.

You may do this in your CSS file :

```
.normalClass:last-child {

}
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myCollection}" var="item"  varStatus="status">
<div class="#{status.last?'last':''}">#{item.text}</div>
</ui:repeat>
```